# Why do I have to do a type cast in the ELSE part of a PostgreSQL update statement using a CASE, but not in the WHEN part?

Tags: postgresql

I have to update a newly created `metadata` table (which holds a 1-1 relations with a `person` table) in PostgreSQL (>=12):

```
UPDATE public.metadata m
  SET print_status =
    CASE
      WHEN p.print IS NOT NULL THEN 'done'
      ELSE 'not done'
    END
  FROM public.people p
  WHERE m.fk_people_id = p.id;
```

but I face this error:

```
ERROR:  column "print_status" is of type print_statuses but expression is of type text
LINE 18:  CASE
          ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
SQL state: 42804
Character: 477
```

`print_statuses` is an enum containing `('done', 'doing', 'not done')`. And the `print_status` column of the `metadata` table is of type `print_statuses` (it also defaults to 'not done', so I wouldn't need the `ELSE` part anymore I guess).

It seems I do have to type cast the 'not done' text in the `ELSE` part of the `CASE` statement like this for this query to work:

```
UPDATE public.metadata m
  SET print_status =
    CASE
      WHEN p.print IS NOT NULL THEN 'done'
      ELSE 'not done'::print_statuses
    END
  FROM public.people p
  WHERE m.fk_people_id = p.id;
```

Why do I have to do a type cast here, and not when using a simple `UPDATE` statement as in:
`UPDATE public.metadata m SET print_status = 'not done' FROM public.people p WHERE g.fk_people_id = i.id;`
?

Comment: I'd say that Postgres doesn't infer the type of the literals from the expected type of the `CASE` expression. It also works if you specify `::print_statuses` in both `THEN` and `ELSE` branches, and I guess it even works if you only specify it in the `THEN` but not in the `ELSE`.

Comment: Yes indeed, if I drop the `ELSE` it will raise the same error.

Comment: See here [Case](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) and  [Case type conversion](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/typeconv-union-case.html). Basically `CASE` can be used in many places and how it handles it's type casting is internal to the `CASE` statement and not what it is being passed to.